# Discord.py Restart Command

Tags: python, discord.py, restart, shutdown

So, i was making a bot and i was wondering if there is a way to restart it using a command like:
`p!restart`
i did like a command:
`p!shutdown`
but cant figure out how to restart, for those who came here looking for a shutdown cmd:

````
async def shutdown(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.author.id)
    if id == 'your_id_here':
        await ctx.send('Shutting down the bot!')
        await ctx.bot.logout()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You dont have sufficient permmisions to perform this action!")```
````

Answer (score 5):

`ctx.bot.logout()` only logs your bot out.

If you want to fully restart your program, this is how I accomplished it:

```py
import sys
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot

def restart_bot(): 
  os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)

@bot.command(name= 'restart')
async def restart(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Restarting bot...")
  restart_bot()

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

In order to prevent potential abuse of this command, just add an "if" statement to your command that checks `ctx.author.id` to see if the user has permission to execute the command. It looks like you did that though.

Answer (score 2):

[`Client.logout()`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logout)

This will simply log you out and then you can log in again by using
[Client.login()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.login)

This is simply what it needs to restart the bot

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Log : "+str(client.user))

@client.command()
async def rs(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Restarting...")
    os.startfile(__file__)
    os._exit(1)

client.run("token")
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do `ctx.bot.close()` which restarts your bot depending on your hosting, idk